# Android Amazon S3 Access Denied

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

We have a backend which get an `identityId` and `token` from Amazon **Cognito** and we have to use these parameters in our iOS and Android apps to upload a file to Amazon S3.

We've been using this Amazon guide (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html) for identifying the app users. We have iOS working but Android always throws the following exception:
`com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;`

Our custom `AWSAbstractCognitoDeveloperIdentityProvider` is the next one:

```
public class WSAuthenticationProvider extends AWSAbstractCognitoDeveloperIdentityProvider {

    public WSAuthenticationProvider(String accountId, String identityPoolId, Regions region) {
        super(accountId, identityPoolId, region);
    }

    public WSAuthenticationProvider(String identityPoolId, Regions region, String identityId, String token) {
        this(null, identityPoolId, region);
        this.identityId = identityId;
        this.token = token;
    }

    // Return the developer provider name which you choose while setting up the
    // identity pool in the &COG; Console
    @Override
    public String getProviderName() {
        return "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com";
    }

    // If the app has a valid identityId return it, otherwise get a valid
    // identityId from your backend.
    @Override
    public String getIdentityId() {
        return identityId;
    }
}
```

We *call* the **TransferUtility** with the following code:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                TransferUtility transferUtility = getTransferUtility();

                // Begin the upload
                TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(AMAZON_S3_BUCKET, "testS3.jpg", new File(uri.getPath()));

            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
}.execute();
```

We *get* the **TransferUtility** with the following code:

```
private TransferUtility getTransferUtility() throws Throwable {

    WSAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new WSAuthenticationProvider(AMAZON_IDENTITY_POOL_ID, Regions.EU_WEST_1, identityId, token);

    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(context, authenticationProvider, Regions.EU_WEST_1);
    Map<String, String> mapLogins = new HashMap<>();
    mapLogins.put(authenticationProvider.getProviderName(), token);
    credentialsProvider.withLogins(mapLogins);

    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
    s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));

    return TransferUtility.builder()
                    .context(context)
                    .s3Client(s3Client)
                    .defaultBucket(AMAZON_S3_BUCKET)
                    .build();
}
```

Are we missing anything? We could not find any good examples or questions about this.
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: For me, it is same implementation like yours, and it's working. Just one thing differs

Try to update `identityId` and `token` in your `WSAuthenticationProvider` class by overriding refresh() method. rather than initializing from Constructor.

Inside `refresh()` method use `update(identityId,token)` method

Comment: Hello Milind and thanks for the response! I did what you said but no success. Same error :(

Comment: Finally it is working. The problem was that we needed the Content-Type and the right directory in the bucket!